# How to setup an ETCD cluster in Kubernetes using DNS discovery (SRV)?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, etcd, srv

I am looking to have a dynamic `etcd` cluster running inside my k8s cluster. The best way I can think of doing it dynamically (no hardcoded addresses, names, etc.) is to use DNS discovery, with the internal k8s DNS (CoreDNS).

I find detached information about `SRV` records created for services in k8s, and some explanations on how `etcd` DNS discovery works, but no complete howto.

For example:

- how does k8s name `SRV` entries?
- should they be named with a specific way for `etcd` to be able to find them?
- should any special CoreDNS setting be set?

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated.

references:

- https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/clustering.html#dns-discovery
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Answer (score 2):

> how does k8s name SRV entries?

via the `Service.port[].name`, which is why almost everything in kubernetes has to be a DNS-friendly name: because a lot of times, it does put them in DNS for you.

A Pod that has `dig` or a new enough `nslookup` will then show you:

```
$ dig SRV kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local.
```

and you'll see the names of the ports that the `kubernetes` `Service` is advertising.

> should they be named with a specific way for etcd to be able to find them?

Yes, as one can see in the page you linked to, they need to be named one of these four:

- `_etcd-client`
- `_etcd-client-ssl`
- `_etcd-server`
- `_etcd-server-ssl`

so something like this on the kubernetes side:

```
ports:
- name: etcd-client
  port: 2379
  containerPort: whatever
- name: etcd-server
  port: 2380
  containerPort: whatever
```